# Arduino mega shield v2.0 compatibility with arduino due

Tags: arduino

Like the title says.. Will it work? I know about the due 3.3 volt limitations.

I want to build a hexapod with 18 servo's.

The shield I am looking at:

http://yourduino.com/sunshop2/index.php?l=product_detail&p=195

If it isn't compatible. Is there an alternative shield which will work? I can't seem to find much for the due.

Comment: Although this is primarily an Arduino question, the fact that we have a good answer and the application is controlling many servos for a hexapod, means that I'm happy for it to be left open here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to plug that shield into either a Due or a Mega, with the caveat that the URF01 pins on the shield may interfere with two sockets of the Power header (IOREF and the opening next to it).  (Older Mega's may have a six-pin Power header rather than eight-pin.)  If there's interference you might need to remove a pin or two from the URF01 group.  Here is a picture of a Due overlaid (at 41% transparency) on top of a Mega:
[image: Due at 41% transparency overlaid on Mega]

The overlay is imperfect (due to slight mispositioning, slight scale errors, and camera distortion) but is good enough to show that the shield should plug in.  The shield appears to have a power-indicator LED on it, but aside from that apparently has no electronics to cause problems.

The photos that I overlaid came from [arduinoBoardMega](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega) and [ArduinoBoardDue](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) or related sites.

The following is from “[nice drawings of the arduino uno and mega 2560](https://blog.arduino.cc/2011/01/05/nice-drawings-of-the-arduino-uno-and-mega-2560/)” on arduino.cc and should let you measure your Due to see if it matches:  [image: mega dimensions diagram]

Numbers in the picture above are in mils, that is, in thousandths of an inch.  Numbers in the picture below (from [hwkitchen.com](http://www.hwkitchen.com/products/arduino-mega-2560/)) are in millimeters.  Note, the picture above is the more-recent R3 version, with 8 pins in the power block, vs the 6 pins in that block in the picture below.  [image]

The thread [shield layout for DUE/Mega](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=148640.0) in forum.arduino.cc also may be of interest.  It suggests the Due and Mega have matching pin layouts.  It also gives links to some CAD files for the boards.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! It's really useful. I ordered the shield. Let's hope it will work!

Comment: @Klaas, yes, let us know how it works out

Comment: @Klaas - It's a good idea to mark answers as useful (the vote up arrow) when you accept an answer, since it would be odd to think than an answer which isn't useful still answered your question.*8')

Comment: I ordered from Aliexpress. Need to wait one month but I will post the results below!

Comment: It work's! the reset button work's too. The mega has some problems with the usb connector(https://www.flickr.com/photos/andrew-d/8171831448), but the due fits perfect.

I only tried with external power connected to the shield though.